# Using .pbf osm formats to show markers

Tags: c#, wpf, openstreetmap

OSM is whole new dimension that i m working in..

i am basically developing WPF application where i have to add specific markers in Pakistan region. I have saved .osm.pbf data for Pakistan.

is there any way to save loading time from .pdf file as in i can save the cache on my disk rather memory and load it directly

and how exactly i will add markers on the data map 
i am following example 
https://github.com/OsmSharp/tile-server

Comment: [.osm](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) and [.osm.pbf](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format) contain raw data and have nothing to do with markers. Please give us some more information what you are trying to do. Displaying pre-rendered [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) or rendering your own? Either way, you will need an additional storage for markers. You can also just add a HTML view to your application and display a map using Leaflet or OpenLayers. It all depends on your specific goal which is not clear from your question.

Comment: my ultimate goal is to show a map, with some pre-configured markers, which is easily achievable on google api.. but the only thing I need in application is to have offline map, where googleapi needs active internet connection

Comment: Then either download/pre-render all the tiles you are going to show or choose one of the [vector tiles](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles) solution.  [MapSurfer.NET](http://mapsurfernet.com/docs/usermanual/data_sources/vector/vectortiles) is written in C# and seems to support vector tiles

Comment: hey thanx scai, created local tile server and used leaflets..